# I like Button - many pages same like button code

Tags: button, facebook-like

Hello I had created a facebook page for a company. I get the FB like button code. The problem that I find is when someone clicks on this button if this user is not on the main page (/index.php) then my facebook like counter (from the facebook page) doesn't count.
I give an example. Lets say that the user when to the home /index.php he makes click on the button I like, then my facebook page count people who said I like +1. But if he goes to some article /article1.php and click there my FB page counter doesn't count +1, how can I solve this problem? because I don't want an static URL pointing always to index.php.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do want sepatate counts for each page?  What does the Facebook linter tool say for each of your URLs?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be happening is facebook might be using the acutall URL of the page for the like URL. For example the main page /index.php may be linked to the actual facebook page. But the /article1.php is being seen by facebook as /article1.php and not /index.php and counting it as 2 separate pages.

One way to fix this might be to make sure that all like buttons are using the same code, and always have the index.php specified as the URL.

The disadvantage to this is, the counts will not reflect the actual likes to the pages, but will be to the site as a whole.

One way to get the full code and you can even specify the URL is to use the following page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Dennis thank you for your answer, the problem of having always the same code is that when people will click on my /article1.php still will show on their facebook pages the information of the home and I would like to publish the information of article1.php no /index.php. There is some way to make facebook take my entire domain as 1 page?